# Graphviz binary graph.left or right nodes alone

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to make tree with dot.

I have root and one node 
let say root is a and the left node is b
I want that when I do a->b the line will be like binary tree that does not have right node
when I do a->b I receive one line from the up to down and I want the line will be more to left...

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you have/want.  Do you need rankdir=LR?  Can you post some images somewhere of what you and what you want it to look like?

Comment: I solved the problem I used rankdir=LR and pos function